# Querying an array of MongoDB Embedded/Nested Documents with Presto

Tags: mongodb, presto, trino

Say I have the following documents:

```
db.inventory.insertMany( [
   { item: "journal", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 5 }, { warehouse: "C", qty: 15 } ] },
   { item: "notebook", instock: [ { warehouse: "C", qty: 5 } ] },
   { item: "paper", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 60 }, { warehouse: "B", qty: 15 } ] },
   { item: "planner", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 40 }, { warehouse: "B", qty: 5 } ] },
   { item: "postcard", instock: [ { warehouse: "B", qty: 15 }, { warehouse: "C", qty: 35 } ] }
]);
```

I want to query on an instock document based on both warehouse and qty. In mongo shell I would do:

```
db.inventory.find( { "instock": { $elemMatch: { qty: 5, warehouse: "A" } } } )
```

How would I do this in Presto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`instock` will be mapped to `array(row(warehouse varchar, qty double))` type and `$elemMatch` is equal to [any_match](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#any_match) array function in Trino (formerly Presto SQL).

```
select * from inventory where any_match(instock, x -> x.qty = 5 and x.warehouse = 'A');
  item   |                      instock
---------+---------------------------------------------------
 journal | [{warehouse=A, qty=5.0}, {warehouse=C, qty=15.0}]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I just tried this and it gives back the correct items, but it doesn't generate an $elemMatch filter underneath, it loads all the data and I think it's doing the filtering within presto. I need the $elemMatch inorder to leverage the database indexes, any ideas here?

Comment: Currently, you can't. Please file an issue to https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/new