# Trino query on MongoDB is not using indexes

Tags: mongodb, trino

Querying mongo data from Trino results in collection scan instead of index scan. Please suggest.

For example, lets say we have below json in mongo

```
{
    "_id": "b4dc8c1d-feb0-41ad-826b-55de1826d63f",
    "event": {
        "status": "create",
        "header": {
            "direction": "DISTRIBUTION",
            "receiver": {
                "address": "street 1"
            },
            "transferReference": "123"
        }
    },
    "extractedFields": [
        {
            "field1": [
                "value1"
            ],
            "field2": [
                "value2"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "domainMetaData": {
      "receivedTime": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1666571260554"
        }
      }
    }
    "statusDate": "2022-08-22T17:19:21.999"
}
```

```
select * from schema.database.table where event.header.transferReference = '123'
```

Field 'genericEvent.header.transferReference' is indexed in Mongo. Explain plan shows filter is pushed to mongo but entire collection is scanned.

ScanFilter[table = schema.database.table, grouped = false, filterPredicate = ("genericevent"[2][3] = VARCHAR '123')]

```
SELECT * FROM schema.database.tablewhere where statusDate  = timestamp '2022-08-22 17:19:21.999'
```

Field statusDate is indexed in Mongo. Explain plan shows filter is pushed to mongo but entire collection is scanned.

```
SELECT * FROM schema.database.tablewhere where _id  = 'b4dc8c1d-feb0-41ad-826b-55de1826d63f'
```

Above SQL query works fine. Index is used and only one record is loaded.

Comment: looks like this is not supported yet https://github.com/trinodb/trino/pull/11556

Comment: yeah. It is discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65635028/querying-an-array-of-mongodb-embedded-nested-documents-with-presto and https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/10119

Answer (score 0):

Index scans are not supported by the [MongoDB connector](https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/mongodb.html). This is a performance improvement that could be added, but is currently not in place.

Comment: This is huge limitation. We have close to 1 TB data in Mongo and a simple query through starburst does not respond at all

Comment: Please work with your support representative for further help, specific to your use case and scenario

Comment: Trino version 399 added support for predicate pushdown on timestamp type. I suppose the case for statusDate column will be faster.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Is 399 released?

Comment: Yes. Download it from https://trino.io/